# link on image extends the image tag

Tags: html

I cannot understand why my a href link extends my picture. I have set a width and height on the picture. [My Example Site](http://vouzalis.com/public.html). I look around on stackoverflow, where I also tried to set the height and width on the a href.

The reason why I use tables is based on the foundation framework for emails.

My code is looking like this:

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <table class="body">
    <tr>
      <td class="center" align="center" valign="top">
        <!-- Logo Start -->
            <table align="center" class="wrapper header float-center background-color__blue">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td class="wrapper-inner">
                    <table align="center" class="container" style="background-color:transparent">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td>
                            <table class="row collapse">
                              <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                  <th>
                                    <a href="https://www.google.dk/"><img src="https://3.imimg.com/data3/HR/NW/MY-18669487/english-images-2-5-animal-care-20p-26s-250x250.jpg" alt="Some text" align="center" class="float-center" width="250" height="80"></a>
                                  </th>
                                  <th class="expander"></th>
                                </tr>
                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            <!-- Logo End -->
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to not have the link escaping the bounds of the picture, you need to set `display: inline-block;` on the `a` element:

```
a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Note that this messes up the image alignment. In order to fix that, you also need to set `text-align: center` on the `th` element:

```
th {
  text-align: center;
}
```

You also set a `line-height` on the `th` element. If you want the image to take up 100% of the `th` height, you either need to remove this, or set this to 0.7:

```
th {
  line-height: 0.7;
}
```

Hope this helps!